# Spark+cassandra java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am trying to read data from cassandra 2.0.6 using Spark. I use datastax drivers.While reading I got an error like " Loss was due to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD". But I included spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 in my pom.xml which has com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD class.Am i missing any other settings or environment variables.

Comment: I tried but not working for me please can u explain, i added jar to sparkConf.setjar() also added the javasparkContext.addjar(); my mvn packaged with shade plugin have given that jar no use please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the connector is on the class-path for the executor using the -cp option or that it is a bundled jar in the spark context (using the SparkConf.addJars() ).

### Edit for Modern Spark

In Spark > 1.X  it's usually recommend that you use the spark-submit command to place your dependencies on the executor classpath. See
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried by using SparkConf.addJars() works perfectly.

Comment: I thought this was taken care of in the build.sbt file when adding: libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0".  Are we bundling it in the spark context because it doesn't get sent to the executors?

Comment: Adding it to your library dependencies means that your code is compiled against that library. It does not mean that your resultant jar will include the libraries it was compiled against. 

To get a "fat" jar with all the dependencies included,  most folks use sbt assembly